# display data into recycler view from sqlite without restart the app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a application that contain `RecyclerView` and `FragmentDialog` , and I get data from user to `sqlite` and all is working ,
but the problem is , when i click into add into `Dialog`, I have to restart the application to display the data , how I can display the data without Restart?

This is my `DialogFragment`

```
public class addAction extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText addTitle, addDesc;
Button add, clear,close;
private DatabaseHelpher db;
String Title,Des;
public addAction() {
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addaction, container, false);
    addTitle = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.todotitle);
    addDesc = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tododescription);
    add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    close = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Close);
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
        }});
    clear = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addTitle.setText("");
            addDesc.setText("");}});
    return rootView;}
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getDialog().setTitle("Add Action");
    db = new DatabaseHelpher(getContext());
}
private void insert() {
    Title = addTitle.getText().toString();
    Des= addDesc.getText().toString();
    db.insertIntoDB(Title, Des);}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (addTitle.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        addTitle.setError(" Title is required!");
    } else if (addDesc.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        addDesc.setError(" Postion is required!");
    }
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"your data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    insert();
}}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<ToDoModule> dbList;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
DatabaseHelpher helpher;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(this);
    dbList= new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
    dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();



    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.AppRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);
    this.dbList =helpher.getDataFromDB();
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            addAction add = new addAction();
            add.show(fm,"fragment_edit_name");
        }});}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

`getdata()` method from `SQlHelper`

```
  public List<ToDoModule> getDataFromDB(){
    List<ToDoModule> modelList = new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
    String query = "select * from "+ TODO_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            ToDoModule model = new ToDoModule();
            model.setActionTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            model.setActionDesc(cursor.getString(2));
            modelList.add(model);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return modelList;
}

}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter   extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

static List<ToDoModule> dbList;
static Context context;
RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ToDoModule> dbList ){
    this.dbList = new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
    this.context = context;
    this.dbList = dbList;
}
@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.actionitems, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.Title.setText(dbList.get(position).getActionTitle());
    holder.Desc.setText(dbList.get(position).getActionDesc());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dbList.size();
}
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    public TextView Title,Desc;
    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        Title = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.todotitle);
        Desc = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.des);
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: You are correctly adding the new item to the list that is used in the adapter ? If so, just call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding and the list should update (Ps. notify data set changed just work for adding or removing itens, if you need to change just an information inside an item, you need to do this inside the adapter or remove and add all the itens again)

Comment: i try this , but the app its not working , if you can describe    you answer with code please

Answer (score 0):

You can implement notification to the adapter when the data gets changed.

Ideally the adapter `RecyclerAdapter`, will be intimated using the following methods.
1) `notifyItemRemoved` 
2) `notifyItemRangeChanged`
3) `notifyItemRangeInserted`

there are other methods available , which can be found in [this API reference link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Now inorder to update the data, use `recyclerAdapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Go through [this reference link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView) more more detailed implementation under section *Notifying the Adapter*

Comment: thank you for answer , iam a beginner in android , how i can apply this in my code ?

Comment: @Mr.Android Go through the link provided and try out. It is having enough explanation.  To know more about the methods, check this link and search for "notify"  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Comment: i cant understand this , please if you can apply this to my code please apply

Answer (score 0):

At first don't do this in your `RecyclerAdapter`:

```
RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ToDoModule> dbList ){
    this.dbList = new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
    this.context = context;
    this.dbList = dbList;
}
```

You shouldn't save `Context` unless you really understand why you need this. Here you don't use it at all. Also the `this.dbList = new ArrayList<ToDoModule>()` is not necessary since you do `this.dbList = dbList` anyway.

You can add an interface to your `addAction` dialog fragment like

```
public class addAction extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public interface OnToDoAddedListener{
        void onTodoAdded();
    }

    private OnToDoAddedListener mToDoAddedListener;
...
    public setOnTodoAddedListener(OnToDoAddedListner listener){
        this.mToDoAddedListener = listener;
    }
}
```

and then call the `mToDoAddedListener.onTodoAdded()` in your `insert()` method.

Then you should add a listener in your `MainActivity.onCreate` method to the `addAction` object and call this code on your `onTodoAdded()` implementation:

```
this.dbList.clear();
this.dbList.addAll(helpher.getDataFromDB();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: thank you for answer but when i add the interface in the addaction , i got error !

Comment: You should add it as an inner public interface of the `addAction` class. See updated answer.

Comment: i do like this but have error in 

public setOnTodoAddedListener(OnToDoAddedListner listener){
        this.mToDoAddedListener = listener;}

Comment: You need to add a member variable `OnToDoAddedListener mToDoAddedListener` in your `addAction` class as you do with other variables.

Answer (score 0):

In your code i'm not seeing where you update the list (Just the button with an add action) so i will explain with a generic example.

Where you instantiate your RecyclerAdapter:

```
final List<ObjectXPTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
list =helpher.getDataFromDB(); 
final RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,list);

fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ObjectXPTO newObject = new ObjectXPTO(); // Just to exemplify, you need to get this object from you database 
            list.add(newObject);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }
    });
```

Resuming, you need to add the new object in the list you used on your adapter and notify the adapter that the data set is changed, so the adapter will update

**Edit:**
If i understand correctly you add the data on your fragment or somewhere out of your Activity, so you need to pass to Activity (where the adapter is) the information that the data changed.

Add this method to MainActivity :

```
public static void updateList(List<ToDoModule> newList){
    dbList.clear();
    dbList.addAll(newList);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So in the fragment, you can pass the new List and update the list in MainActivity, or you can do a new query inside this method.

This is just for explaining, you may need to compare (outside the UI thread) if an item is not in the list and only add the items that are not already inside (to avoid the whole list to get updated).

Ps. You you need to change the list and adapter variables to static.

Comment: thank you for answer iam try to update list in the DialogFragment on button add click ! ,, when i click you this button , i want to add data from user to sqlite then display it when click close button , try to edit you answer please

Comment: What part you need ? You already add the data in the sqlite ? You already notify the MainActivity (where your adapter is declared) that the information has changed ?

Comment: you have two ways to go, when the fragment add the information, in your Main activity do a query, update your list and notify the adapter, or the second one (witch i think it's the best way) in your adapter build a Listener to update automatically, this second is bit more complex, so i think it's a little out of the question here

Comment: i need when click into add , and add the data to the table in sqlite , display it into recycler view , in this case i have to restart the app to show the data , i want a solution to display without restart !

Comment: so you already add the data in the sqlite, after you add the data, you do something in the MainActivity or the activity is never notified ?

Comment: this is my question how can i notify ? i tried  `            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
` but its not working !